# Is IOS ad hoc distribution useful for personal apps?

Tags: ipad, ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I am considering buying an iPad primarily to run applications that I would program myself. I've created the applications in XCode and run them in the simulator, so I know they will work. My plan would be to buy the iPad, join the developer program as an individual and then upload the programs to my device. I have no interest in putting the applications on the app store as they would not be useful to others.

Reading the description of the developer program, it seems like this would work. But I'd like confirmation from someone in the program that there aren't any hidden gotchas before I take the plunge. I don't need the iPad if I can't run my custom apps.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely no problem with provisioning your own apps for distribution to your own device. I'm doing the same (except I'm using an iPhone). Just bear in mind that you have to re-add your iPad to the provisioning portal each year as the device count will be reset so your apps can continue running on it.

You may of course want to build something for the App Store so you can recoup the $99 annual investment you spend on the developer program, but that's up to you :)

Comment: +1 I've made a number of Ad Hoc iOS apps. I've even seen people release Ad Hoc iOS apps to paying customers because they couldn't get app store approval -- which is not something you should necessarily plan on doing, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

The main limitation is that adhoc certificates expire, so you'll have to build a new version of the app annually and people who have it will need to reinstall.

If you've beta-tested or installed any adhoc apps, look at: Settings -> General -> Profiles to see the various profiles that are installed on your device and when they expire.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you can deploy to your own device at will. It would be awful hard to develop on a device you can't deploy to.

Technically it isn't ad hoc, it's your developer certificate for personal apps on your own device. Ad hoc is to send testing builds to other people.